# How do I install Ubuntu with RAID and full disk encryption and UEFI?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, uefi, encryption, raid

I have a slightly unusual setup which I am failing to get running:

-Dell Precision Laptop with two identical NVME SSDs
-I'd like to install Ubuntu to them with RAID 0 and full disk encryption
-The Device uses UEFI booting, Secure Boot is turned off

The Ubuntu Desktop installer requires me to set up the RAID before the installer, then I can select automatic partitioning with encryption on the combined RAID partition, but then it fails to install GRUB. I also tried the server installer, it allows me to set up RAID and the encryption, but still doesn't install GRUB. I have read that I need to manually create a 200MB FAT32 partition for the boot loader but that also didn't work.

How exactly should my partitioning layout look like? Should the FAT32 partition be on both drives? Should they also be in RAID? Or is there some way I should manually install the boot loader afterwards and add the entries to the UEFI?

Comment: I do not know RAID nor LVM/encryption. But your configuration will require a very good backup procedure. RAID 0 is just for speed like gaming or compiling system, but using data from server elsewhere. And encryption needs good backups as often corruption is difficult or impossible to repair. You do need an ESP - efi system partition as that is only way UEFI can boot. Older installs also have /boot, but I believe grub can now boot into LVM, but not sure with RAID. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu